# Не получается использовать картинки в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Перерыл много страниц с тем, где пишут, как использовать картинки из папки с проектом, делаю так, к примеру:

```
    import {img} from './images/logo.jpg';
    ...
    <img src={img} alt="logo" />
```

Но картинка никак не отображается. В чем проблема?
Пробовал также через require(''), но тоже не работает

Comment: {} фигурные скобки здесь  import {img} from './images/logo.jpg'; лишние

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема скобок в импорте... проверил

```
import logo from './logo.svg';

<img src={logo} alt="logo"/>
```